# Disable form field based on datepicker selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a form with a datepicker where people can book tours. There is an additional Yes/No drop-down on the form that I want to have automatically disabled if they choose a date in December. My datepicker also has disabled dates. The datepicker seems to be working, but I cannot seem to get the selected month from the datepicker returned anywhere (I've tried printing it to screen, using it in an alert, etc.) Obviously there's something wrong with my code but I'm not a JS/jQuery expert so I can't figure it out on my own!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// INITIALIZE DATEPICKER
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#myDatepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: unavailableDates,
            changeMonth: true,
            minDate: 1
    });

});

// DISABLE DATES WITHIN DATEPICKER & GET MONTH  
function unavailableDates(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
                    if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, theUnavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }

        var selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
        if (selectedMonth == 11) {
            jQuery("#tourExtras").hide();
            alert("this means its working");
        }
        else {
            jQuery("tourExtras").show();
            alert("this means its not working");
        }
}   

// DISABLED DATES 
var theUnavailableDates = ["1-1-2014", "2-1-2014", "3-1-2014"];
```

Right now I can't even get the alerts to work, so I'm assuming it's something to do with how I'm doing `var selectedMonth = date.getMonth();` etc.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function "unavailableDates(date)" seems to be right, but i think the property "beforeShowDay" of datepicker it's not what you want.

According to [jQueryUI's Datepicker API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow):

[image]

So, i think the function that you want is: onSelect

[image]

Your code should be like this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        unavailableDates(dateText);
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: 1
});

// DISABLE DATES WITHIN DATEPICKER & GET MONTH  
function unavailableDates(dateText) {
    var date = new Date(dateText); //convert text to date

        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, theUnavailableDates) == -1) {
            alert("this date is NOT on theUnavailableDates array");
            //do something
        } else {
            alert("this date is on theUnavailableDates array!")
            //do something
        }

    var selectedMonth = date.getMonth() + 1; //the month is based on jan=0,feb=1,...
    if (selectedMonth == 11) {
        jQuery("#tourExtras").hide();
        alert("this is november");        
    }
    else {
        jQuery("tourExtras").show();
        alert("this is not november");
    }
}   

// DISABLED DATES 
var theUnavailableDates = ["1-1-2014", "2-1-2014", "3-1-2014"];
```

You can check it on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7FJV/).

Comment: Hey, thanks! Now my question is how do I pass dateText through alert? Or better still, how do I read dateText and say if it equals the month of December, then display the alert?

Comment: Knowing that dateText is an string, you must convert it to Date at the beggining of your function, and the rest continue equals.
You can convert string to date using: new Date("date in string format").  
So, the beggining of your function will be like this: 
function unavailableDates(dateText) {
    var date = new Date(dateText);
    ... (the rest of your function)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! It works with the "disabled dates" lines commented out, but it doesn't work if I try to leave that active (it's important that the disabled dates work - is it possible to get both of these things working together?) - is it because there's now 2 variables called "date" ?

Comment: I don't understand that part. What you want with return [true, ""]; ?
What must be the behavior if the user select an unavailable date?

Comment: I just copied that "disable dates" part from someone else's code and was able to make it work for me. There is an `if...else` statement, but nothing is being returned (at least that the user can see). Basically all this section does is check to see if the dates generated by the array match the dates that are listed to disable, then makes it so they can't be selected within the datepicker. Does this help?

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle. You can just put your logic inside that if, because it is working. Check as answered if this answers your question. =)

Comment: I can't put the disabled dates logic inside the `if...else` statement though because then it only applies if they select a date in December. I need the specific dates disabled regardless of what date they pick (in fact, the dates need to be disabled when the datepicker is loaded so that they cannot choose these dates to begin with)

Comment: Nevermind - I managed to get it working by splitting them into 2 separate functions and running the Disabled Dates on beforeShowDay. Thanks so much for all your help!